# Parquet file format for hbase

Tags: hbase, schema, parquet

I am able to load csv files to hbase and also play with java api. I am also able to query using the hbase shell.

Is there a way I can load parquet files ( say bulk load ) to hbase?
Either through hbase shell or the java api.

I also read that it is possible using `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver`, but dont see any examples of the same.

It will be helpful to get more comments in this regard.

Thanks